# Jquery validation not working if validation fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a real-time jquery validation for name. It is working on real time but when i submit my form it submit the value even after displaying error message.
This is my code for validation:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var $regexname=/^([a-zA-Z]{3,16})$/;
  $('.firstname ').on('keypress keydown keyup',function(){
         if (!$(this).val().match($regexname)) {
             $('.fname').removeClass('hidden');
             $('.fname').show();
         }
       else{
            $('.fname').addClass('hidden');
           }
     });
    });
```

Anyone please help me that when error message displays form doesnot get submit.

Comment: try event.preventDefault()

Comment: The error message wont stop the form to be submitted

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
 $('.firstname ').on('keypress keydown keyup',function(event){
         if (!$(this).val().match($regexname)) {
             event.preventDefault();
             $('.fname').removeClass('hidden');
             $('.fname').show();
         }
       else{
            $('.fname').addClass('hidden');
           }
     });
```

Comment: This code stopped to take any input. I can't type anythning after using this code

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault` **OR** `return false`;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $regexname=/^([a-zA-Z]{3,16})$/;
$('.firstname ').on('keypress keydown keyup',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!$(this).val().match($regexname)) {
            $('.fname').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.fname').show();
        }
    else{
        $('.fname').addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $regexname=/^([a-zA-Z]{3,16})$/;
$('.firstname ').on('keypress keydown keyup',function(event){           
        if (!$(this).val().match($regexname)) {
            $('.fname').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.fname').show();
        }
        else{
            $('.fname').addClass('hidden');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: In your second example the if statement will never execute as you have returned.

Answer (score 0):

**return false** if your validation fails and **true** if it passes.

so, the code I will suggest you to write in your function is...

```
$('.firstname ').on('keypress keydown keyup',function(event){
         if (!$(this).val().match($regexname)) {

             $('.fname').removeClass('hidden');
             $('.fname').show();
             return false;
         }
       else{
            $('.fname').addClass('hidden');
            return true;
           }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add button click event validation to check whether error is visible or not.

```
    $('#buttonId').on('click',function(){
    if($('.fname').is(':visible'))
    {
    alert('Resolve error before submitting the form.');
    return false;
    }
    })
```